# Bitbucket and Database Development

Tags: sql-server, bitbucket

1. I have a Windows server with MS SQL Server running on it.
2. On the SQL Server developers have created stored procedures, views, tables, triggers.
3. On the Windows server developers created shell scripts.

I would like to start versioning the code described above in a BitBucket repository. I have a repository created in BitBucket.

1. How should the branches be organized in this repository? i.e. "SQL Server\Database\\ ...
   "Windows Server\\shell_script" ...
2. Can I connect BitBucket to SQL Server and Windows Server and specify which code needs to be versioned?

Are both 1 and 2 options above possible?

3. I just need to version control the changes to the code and have the ability to mark under which project the code change was made.

I am new to BitBucket. I am using the web front end of it. I do not know how to configure command line access, so please try not to reference Bitbucket commands. Sorry if I sound confusing.

Please help.

Comment: Not sure how your question helps to answer my question.

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver) It will do the heavy lifting for you but you probably would need a build server anyway, something like [bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) since you are using bitbucket

Comment: Bamboo would actually listen on any commits in your repository( you need to set it up). Basically, bitbucket would keep the scripts and version it and bamboo will run them for you in the environment you point it to, but you really need to read about it - it is a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but anyway, in principle I'd recommend:

1. Put all the server shell scripts into one place and make that a git repo linked to your bitbucket repo
2. Add a server shell script to export what you want version controlled from the SQL db

   - The export from the SQL db should be to text files so they are easily 'diffable'
   - You might as well make the export to a sub-directory within the shell scripts repo so that everything is in one place and can't get out of sync
   - So you only have one branch, not a separate one for server shell scripts and db
3. Make sure people run the export script and then commit everything when they make a change

You ideally have a test server which means you'd want a way to push changes from the repo into the SQL db.  I presume you can do this with a script but deleting the server setup and re-creating it from the text files.

So basically, you can't connect an SQL db to bitbucket directly.  You need scripts to read and write to the db from a repo.